# sql child of parents and child of childs

Tags: sql, ms-access

parent_id 0 category 1 
parent_id 0 category 2 
parent_id 0 category 3 
parent_id 1 category 4 
parent_id 1 category 5 
parent_id 2 category 6 
parent_id 2 category 7 
parent_id 3 category 8 
parent_id 4 category 9 
parent_id 4 category 10

I need sql where statement to get categories with parent_id 0 and parent_id parent_id 0. in the above table i will get categories 1 - 8 only

thanks in advance

Comment: I only see the id's of parents, where are the children?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually have an `id` in the table that `parentid` refers to, you can use a subquery in the `where` clause to look up the grandparent:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.parentid = 0 or
      (select t2.parentid
       from t as t2
       where t2.id = t.parentid and t2.parentid
      ) = 0;
```